# Count occurrence of a data in a Multidimensional array

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

need a help. I want to count number of occurrence of a data in a multi dimensional array using PHP but cant solve the problem using for each. So I am asking for help

Sample array

```
Array ( [0] => Array ( [id] => 100 [keys] => Array ( [0] => Array ( [id] => x181 ) [1] => Array ( [id] => x853 ) [2] => Array ( [id] => x890 ) ) )
[1] => Array ( [id] => 101 [keys] => Array ( [0] => Array ( [id] => x133 ) ) )
[2] => Array ( [id] => 102 [keys] => Array ( [0] => Array ( [id] => x904) [1] => Array ( [id] => x102 ) ) )
[3] => Array ( [id] => 103 [keys] => Array ( [0] => Array ( [id] => x121 ) ) ) )
```

I want to count number of occurrences of each IDs, for example

```
x181 1
x121 1 ...
```

Comment: array_count_values()?

Comment: @AbraCadaver its not `date` its `data`

Comment: Same solution @Thamilan